# Update Slider Navigation controller Height

Tags: ios, swift

I am using right Slider menu in my application in which i have set `NavigationController` height but if we are navigating through slider menu options then the view show the default height of slider navigation controller.

Navigation Bar Height:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:self.view.frame.size.width, height:80)
```

In slider menu, we are navigating like this:

```
let mainViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController") as! MainViewController
self.loginViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainViewController)

self.slideMenuController()?.changeMainViewController(self.allPhotosViewController, close: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you can't did customization in Default `NavigationBar` frame but yes it is possible with `CustomNavigationBar`.

Create `CustomNavigationBar` extend from `UIView` & make design as per need .

[image]

Comment: Could you please tell how to make it custom?

Comment: Hi Puja i have updated answer. Have quick look & google for CustomNavigationBar. best luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for what @Mukesh has shown:

```
import UIKit

class CustomNavigationBar: UINavigationBar
{
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)
    {
        // Drawing code
        self.frame.size.height = 90
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    }
}
```

You don't need a Xib file. You can just create a Swift file and then in you Storyboard file edit the NavigationBar `Custom Class` : `Class` which is what @Mukesh has done in his screen shot. I have tested it and it works.